# How to generate your classes in a specific folder with Angula2 CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I usually generate classes with the angular 2 cli with the following command:

`ng g class todo`

How can I tell the cli to generate the classes in a particular folder, for example a models folder.

The documentation has an example where they generate a component in a specific folder but I've had no success with the class option

I've tried the following options:

`ng g class models/todo`

`ng g class ../models todo`

`ng g class models todo`

They result in either an error that the path is invalid, which makes me think that the option is supported but I can't figure it out or in the case of the latter merges the intended folder name with the class name.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Generated items for the Angular CLI are relative...

if you are in the root dir (or the source dir) you are perceived to be in the app dir...

```
~/me/foo > ng g c bar
// ~/me/foo/src/app/bar/bar.component*

~/me/foo/src > ng g c bar
// ~/me/foo/src/app/bar/bar.component*
```

if you are in the app directory or further down the folder structure you will generate to where you are...

```
~/me/foo/src/app/feature > ng g c bar
// ~/me/foo/src/app/feature/bar/bar.component*

~/me/foo/src/app/feature > ng g c ../bar
// ~/me/foo/src/app/bar/bar.component*
```

Note: if you try to generate into a dir that does not exist, it will error...

```
~/me/foo/src/app > ng g c a/b/c/d/e/f/g/bar
// Error
```

Comment: The component example already worked (that was in the documentation), what I'm interested is in classes, nonetheless your answer did provide the key: if I create the folder before hand I can generate the class directly to it.

Comment: class generation works the same way , except classes don't generate their own directory by default.

Comment: Yes that is the whole point of my question can I generate a specific directory when I generate my class, the cli can't but if I create the folder before hand I can generate the class directly in it from the cli.

Comment: OK. I'd suggest you add your thoughts/opinions to this github issue... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2806

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 11):

To create a todo component inside the models folder in your project, just make sure you are in the project's root folder and type:

> ng g c /models/todo

Also, if you want to specify a the declaring module's file name, you can use the -m option.

For example, if you have a models module, and want to update that module for declare your new todo's component:

> ng g c /models/todo -m model

Regards

Comment: this create a component not a class

Comment: use `ng g class` instead (`ng g cl` in Angular 5). One full day lost with the `ng g c` command

Answer (score 7):

```
 ng g cl model/UserInfo
works fine in angular5
```

Answer (score 7):

For generating class in Angular 4/5/6

Just right click on the folder in which you want to create the class and select the folder *open in terminal*

then inside the terminal  use

```
ng g class classname --type=model
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ng generate component my-new-component

ng g component my-new-component # using the alias
```

components support relative path generation

if in the directory `src/app/feature/` and you run

```
ng g component new-cmp
```

your component will be generated in `src/app/feature/new-cmp`

but if you were to run

```
ng g component ../newer-cmp
```

your component will be generated in `src/app/newer-cmp`

that works for classes also

check : [Github angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: could please you post the exact command I should use I tried with the one you posted and it didn't work.

Comment: ng g class app/models/todo (u begin by the app folder)

Comment: The first suggestion gave a path error, the second didn't create a models folder but created a class with models in the name.

Comment: can u give me the structure of ur project !

Comment: It's the basic project structure, what I get after ng new application_name, what version of the cli and node are you using ?

Comment: And the latest command you entered still gives me the path error, I haven't modified the structure of the folders that ng created for me so in that respect I'm safe.

Comment: angular-cli : 1.0.0-beta.17
node : 4.2.4
webpack : 2.1.0-beta.25
typescript : 2.0.3

Answer (score 3):

adding to Karthikeyan Karunanithi simple answer,

```
ng g i model/UserInfo
```

works great if you wanted an interface...

Answer (score 3):

```
ng g cl models//todo-class
```

result [~/project/src/app/models/todo-class.ts](http://src/app/models/todo-class.ts)

```
export class TodoClass {}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services

Generating Components, *Classes*, Directives, Guards, Interfaces, Enums, Pipes and Services, *Modules*, *Libraries*

You can use the ng generate (or just ng g) command to generate Angular artifacts:

```
ng generate component my-new-component
ng g component my-new-component # using the alias
```

## components support relative path generation

## if in the directory src/app/feature/ and you run

```
ng g component new-cmp
```

## your component will be generated in src/app/feature/new-cmp

## but if you were to run

```
ng g component ./newer-cmp
```

## your component will be generated in src/app/newer-cmp

## if in the directory src/app you can also run

```
ng g component feature/new-cmp
```

## and your component will be generated in src/app/feature/new-cmp

You can find all possible blueprints in the table below:

```
Scaffold    Usage
Component   ng g component my-new-component
Directive   ng g directive my-new-directive
Pipe    ng g pipe my-new-pipe
Service ng g service my-new-service
**Class ng g class my-new-class**
Guard   ng g guard my-new-guard
Interface   ng g interface my-new-interface
Enum    ng g enum my-new-enum
Module  ng g module my-module
```

angular-cli will add reference to components, directives and pipes automatically in the app.module.ts. If you need to add this references to another custom module, follow this steps:

`ng g module new-module` 
to create a new module

call 
`ng g component new-module/new-component`

This should add the new component, directive or pipe reference to the new-module you've created.